# Redemption RDOSession needs email-programm?

Tags: outlook-redemption

I try to use Redemption with vbScript but without installed Outlook, because the homepage says:

> RDO (Redemption Data Objects) library is designed to be used as a
> complete Outlook Object Model (OOM) or CDO 1.21 replacement. This
> family of objects is designed to be used standalone, but it can of
> course still be used along with your existing Outlook Object Model
> code.
> http://dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm

But the call

```
Set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
```

produces an error:

[image: errormessage]

The operating system is Windows Server 2016 Standard.

My question: Do I need Outlook or not? Or what am I doing wrong?

With many thanks in advance
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since Redemption is a wrapper around the Extended MAPI system, MAPI needs to be installed, which means Outlook mus also be installed.

Also make sure the bitness of your code matches the bitness of Outlook - see http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#ErrorCreatingRedemptionObject

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is not the answer I had hoped for, but it creates clarity...
And thanks for the great tool redemption is!

Comment: You can still install the standalone version of MAPI (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42040), but it does not support Unicode MSG and PST files, and cannot connect to Exchange 2016 or higher.

Comment: Thanks again - we found a other solution; the problem was converting eml 2 msg,,, now it is solved